# Exporting ODBC System DSNs from a windows 2003 machine?

Tags: odbc, export, windows-server-2003

Is there a way to export all the ODBC System DSNs from a windows 2003 machine?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

System DSN information is stored under the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI` registry key. You could export that key to a .reg file and import on another machine.

UPDATE:

You can also do it programmatically. Here are a few examples:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/DSNAdmin.aspx

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/110507

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2004/11/10/can-i-create-and-delete-a-dsn-using-a-script.aspx

Comment: Thanks Garett for your answer!

Comment: Does this depend on the server version you are exporting to? What if I am exporting to a Windows 2008 server?

Comment: @KyleJohnson I believe this will work with Windows 2008, but I don't have a version of 2008 to verify this at the moment. I've verified this under 64-bit Windows 7 if that helps at all.

Answer (score 7):

I have just done this myself with a very simple bat script for 32bit ODBC sources

```
regedit /e c:\backup\odbc.reg "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC\ODBC.INI"
```

and for the 64bit sources or if you are on a 32bit operating system:

```
regedit /e c:\backup\odbc.reg "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI"
```

This backs up all of the DSN's however you could then specify the DNS you want.

Comment: On windows server 64 bit it's "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI"

Answer (score 2):

System DSN's are stored in windows registry under `HKLM\Software\ODBC\ODBC.INI` node
So if you export this node to a *.reg file and run this reg file on a target machine, it should work.

The only thing, this reg file will contain some file paths which maybe computer specific, eg
`c:\WINNT\System32\bla-bla-bla.dll` includes WINNT folder which on target machine may be called like `WINDOWS`. So you will need to spend a bit time to make sure all paths in *.reg file are correct for target machine where you would finally import.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote some Powershell functions for copying ODBC connections from one computer to another, they are posted (and kept updated) at:

http://powershell.com/cs/media/p/32510.aspx

```
# Usage:  
# $srcConfig = Get-OdbcConfig srcComputerName   
# Import-OdbcConfig trgComputerName $scrConfig  
# Only returns data when setting values  

function Get-OdbcConfig {  
param( $srcName )  
    if ( Test-Connection $srcName -Count 1 -Quiet ) {  
        # cycle through the odbc and odbc32 keys  
        $keys = "SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI", "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC\ODBC.INI"  
        foreach ( $key in $keys ){  
            # open remote registry  
            $type = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::LocalMachine  
            $srcReg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey( $type, $srcName )  
            $OdbcKey = $srcReg.OpenSubKey( $key )  
            # red through each key  
            foreach ( $oDrvr in $OdbcKey.GetSubKeyNames() ){  
                # form the key path  
                $sKey = $key + "\" + $oDrvr  
                $oDrvrKey = $srcReg.OpenSubKey( $sKey )  
                # cycle through each value, capture the key path, name, value and type  
                foreach ( $oDrvrVal in $oDrvrKey.GetValueNames() ) {  
                        $regObj = New-Object psobject -Property @{  
                        Path = $sKey  
                        Name = $oDrvrVal  
                        Value = $oDrvrKey.GetValue( $oDrvrVal )  
                        Type = $oDrvrKey.GetValueKind( $oDrvrVal )  
                    }  
                # dump each to the console  
                $regObj  
                }  
            }  
        }  
    }  
    # can't ping  
    else { Write-Host "$srcName offline" }  
}  

function Import-OdbcConfig {  
param( $trgName, $srcConfig )  
    if ( Test-Connection $trgName -Count 1 -Quiet ) {  
        # open remote registry  
        $type = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::LocalMachine  
        $trgReg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey( $type, $trgName )  
        # sort out the key paths and cycle through each  
        $paths = $srcConfig | select -Unique Path  
        foreach ( $key in $paths ){  
            # check for the key and create it if it's not there  
            if ( ! $trgReg.OpenSubKey( $key.Path ) ) { $writeKey = $trgReg.CreateSubKey( $key.Path ) }  
            # open the path for writing ($true)  
            $trgKey = $trgReg.OpenSubKey( $key.Path, $true )  
            # cycle through each value, check to see if it exists, create it if it doesn't  
            foreach ( $oDrvr in $srcConfig | where { $_.Path -eq $key.Path } ) {  
                if ( ! $trgKey.GetValue( $oDrvr.Name ) ) {  
                    $oType = $oDrvr.Type  
                    $writeValue = $trgKey.SetValue( $oDrvr.Name, $oDrvr.Value, [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::$oType  )  
                    $objObj = new-object psobject -Property @{  
                        Path = $oDrvr.Path  
                        Name = $oDrvr.Name  
                        Value = $trgKey.GetValue( $oDrvr.Name )  
                        Type = $trgKey.GetValueKind( $oDrvr.Name )  
                    }  
                }  
            $objObj  
            }  
        }  
    }  
    # can't ping  
    else { Write-Host "$srcName offline" }  
}
```

Using these functions together you can copy all of one computers ODBC connections to another:

$srcConfig = Get-OdbcConfig srcComputerName
Import-OdbcConfig trgComputerName $scrConfig

It's possible to include only your favorite ODBC connection by filtering on the path:

```
Import-OdbcConfig trgComputerName ( $scrKeys | where { $_.Path -eq "SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\GoodDatabase" } )
```

Or filtering out ODBC connections you don't like:

```
Import-OdbcConfig trgComputerName ( $scrKeys | where { $_.Path -ne "SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\DatabaseIHate" } )
```

Import-OdbcConfig only returns data when setting values or can't ping target, if there's nothing to create it won't say anything.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find the registrations there, depending on if they are User DSN/System DSN, they can very will be in:

> [HKEY_USERS\"User SID(dont' look for this, it will be a long
>   number)\Software\ODBC\ODBC.INI]